# Perf4J @Profiled annotation + log4j is not working

Tags: annotations, log4j, aspectj, perf4j

I have got the following problem: I want to monitor the execution time of some low-performance methods by using perf4j @Profiled annotation and log4j. 
The problem is the monitoring log file is empty and looks like this:

```
Performance Statistics   2013-07-17 18:07:50 - 2013-07-17 18:08:00
Tag                                                  Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count

Performance Statistics   2013-07-17 18:08:00 - 2013-07-17 18:08:10
Tag                                                  Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count
```

The log4j.xml is contained in projectRoot/conf/exp directory and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd"><log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="./logs/exp-log.txt"/>
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}    %c          %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<appender name="CoalescingStatistics"
          class="org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">

    <param name="TimeSlice" value="10000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>

    <appender-ref ref="graphExecutionTimes"/>
    <appender-ref ref="graphExecutionTPS"/>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="./logs/perfStats.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="graphExecutionTimes"
          class="org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender">
    <!-- Possible GraphTypes are Mean, Min, Max, StdDev, Count and TPS -->
    <param name="GraphType" value="Mean"/>
    <!-- The tags of the timed execution blocks to graph are specified here -->
    <param name="TagNamesToGraph" value="firstBlock,secondBlock"/>
    <appender-ref ref="graphsFileAppender"/>
</appender>

<appender name="graphExecutionTPS"
          class="org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender">
    <param name="GraphType" value="TPS"/>
    <param name="TagNamesToGraph" value="firstBlock,secondBlock"/>
    <appender-ref ref="graphsFileAppender"/>
</appender>

<appender name="graphsFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="./logs/perfGraphs.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CoalescingStatistics"/>
</logger>

<logger name="sui">
<level value="debug"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="logfile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I have got the following annotations in my sources:

```
@Profiled(tag = "exportRecsForAccount")
    protected void exportRecsForAccount(NetSuiteAcctInfo acctInfo) {

@Profiled(tag = "exportRecsForEachAccount")
    protected boolean exportRecsForEachAccount() throws QueueManagerException, CriticalDBConnectionFailed {
```

Besides that, I have got the aop.xml located in projectRoot/recources/META-INF. Its content is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">

<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.perf4j.log4j.aop.TimingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="comp.sui.ExportService"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

where comp.sui.ExportService is a link to the source code class.

So the question is what am I doing wrong? When I use StopWatches stamps everything is all right, but with @Profiled annotations seems nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">

<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.perf4j.log4j.aop.TimingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="comp.sui.ExportService"/>

        <!-- Weave in perf4j aspects for Aspectj 1.6.7+ -->
        <include within="org.perf4j.slf4j.aop.*"/>
        <include within="org.perf4j.aop.*"/>
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```